# Return response.data in function inside .then callback | Axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Is it possible to return a function inside the `.then` callback?

I want to do something like this:

```
axios.post('url_api/endpoint')
  .then(function(response){

     renderAdmissionReponse(){
       <div>Success response.data</div>
     }

  })
```

To later render it in a component like this: "

```
<div className="row spacer">
 {this.renderAdmissionReponse()}
</div>
```

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: **NO**. Since its react, you can call that function in outside render, and `then` will update the `state` which ultimately updated the UI

Comment: Ok so basically something like this:
`axios.post('url_api/endpoint')
  .then(function(response){
   this.setState({ admissionResponse: response.data }) 

  })`

Comment: yes, whats you `admissionResponse` format?

Comment: Its a JSON format

Comment: Its an object content: in order to render that I did this: `const admissionResponseJSON = JSON.stringify(this.state.admissionResponse, null, 2)`

Comment: I mean whats the value of it, something like  `[{name:"something", class: 10}, {...}]` ?

Comment: its something like this

`{
  "authorizationId": "mdym02f2-7776-8496-0054-070100000004",
  "authorizationNum": "IP0000003523",
  "status": "PEND",
  "state": "OPEN",
  "version": 4,
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "id": "mdym02f2-7776-8496-0054-070100000005",
      "lineItemNumber": 1,
      "unitCountDetermined": 0,
      "unitCountApproved": 0,
      "unitCountDenied": 0
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can actually understand your need, however, your above code is wrong!

What you want is: after data are loaded successfully by using axios, the data will be rendered properly on page. If so, you can use the following way:

```
constructor(props) {
    // ...
    this.state = ({
        admissionResponse: [],
        // your other state variables here
    })
}

renderAdmissionReponse = (data) => {
    this.setState({
        admissionResponse: data,
    });
}

// ... You can put this inside `ComponentDidMount()`, then just call the function to setState with returned data
axios.post('url_api/endpoint')
    .then((response) => {

        this.renderAdmissionReponse(response.data);

    })
// ...

render() {
    return (
        <div className="row spacer">
            <div>{this.state.admissionResponse.authorizationId}</div>
            <div>{this.state.admissionResponse.authorizationNum}</div>
            {this.state.admissionResponse.lineItems.map((line) =>{
              return(
                <div>{line.id}</div>
                <div>{line.lineItemNumber}</div>
              )
            })}  
        </div>
    );
}
```

Please also check your response.data structure then retrieve the correct keys, the above code I just try to explain about correct react's way on how to load data asynchronously and render on page after that. Please post here some errors if any, thanks.

Comment: Glad you've got it working ^^ ! Feel free to ping me for further react's issues, thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will